# SpookyJS each() method

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

In SpookyJS, is there an "each" function equivalent to that of Casper's?

http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#each

Comment: I guess you could answer it yourself now.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? I saw your post on the SpookyJS github page but the answers did not work for me, they were kind of vague

Comment: i don't think i did. however, you can actually solve this by adding a loop inside of a `then` block, and having the loop create a `then` block on each iteration.